# Print to PDF (Not save as PDF) in Excel

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I was wondering if there is a way to print to pdf. My company has a software installed as a printer (ScanSoft pdf). The reason I need to print as a pdf and not save is as follows:

- My default printer can only print letter documents. I have few routines that format the excel document that I am working on to a tabloid document. And the since I my default printer can't support 11x17 (Tabloid). The page breaks are defaulted to letter document settings. And the tabloid is not an option in the size options. If I go and select the print and select a pdf and exit the print dialogue without saving - the page breaks are converted to the tabloid settings. I have another routine that runs through the document and adjusts the page breaks to avoid splitting merged cells.

What I am looking for at end of the day, run the routine to format document, run a routine to print as pdf then exit dialogue (to adjust page breaks), run routine to adjust page breaks, run routine to save pdf.

[enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/893023/excel-vba-is-there-a-command-for-printing-to-pdf-dopdf-ver-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set your activeprinter to the pdf printer

```
 Application.ActivePrinter ="what ever your printer is called"
```

To find out what it's called, set it as the activeprinter manually and then in the immediate window just type

```
 ? Application.ActivePrinter
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. So this is what shows up as the name: "ScanSoft PDF Create! on Ne00:". Any idea if this will change from computer to computer. What is the Ne00, another printer came up as Ne03. I am working on an application that will be used by a wide range of computers.

And is there a way to loop through all the printers and just capture the name of one that has the word 'pdf' in it?

Comment: Found this to loop through printers. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/GetPrinters.aspx